# Javascript: Getting not a function error when invoking inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error when I invoke a prototype function inside of a loop.

The class

```
var Book = function(title, Available, publicationDate, checkoutDate, callNumber, Authors) {
    this.title = title;
    this.Available = false;
    this.publicationDate = new Date();
    this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
    this.callNumber = 690080;
    this.Authors = Authors;
};
```

Other class with has the booksOut array property

```
var Patron = function(firstName, lastName, libCardNum, booksOut, fine) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.libCardNum = libCardNum;
    this.booksOut = [];
    this.fine = 0.00;
};
```

The prototype which is supposed to add the book to the array property in the patron class

```
Patron.prototype.read = function(Book) {
    this.booksOut.add(Book);
}
```

The loop that cause the TypeError: catalog[k].read is not a function error with the parenthesis and without them it always gives the same output.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < catalog.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < patrons.length; k++) {
            var fine = patrons[k].fine;
            if (catalog[k].Available) {
                catalog[k].checkOut();
            } else {
                catalog[k].checkIn();
                catalog[k].read();
                if (catalog[k].isOverdue()) {
                    fine = fine + 5.00;
                }
            }
            patrons[k].fine = fine;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `catalog`? It it is an instance of `Book` then it does not have the `read` method, which is defined for `Patron`, not `Book`. Also, it seems to expect an argument.... Calling that parameter `Book` is not the best choice, as it can be misunderstood as being the `Book` constructor. Use init-caps only for constructors/classes.

Comment: Figured it out, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your question you haven't stated clearly what `catalog[k]` is...
But I'm assuming it is of type `Book`, because it has properties like `Available`.
Then the error makes sense because you didn't define any method `read` for `Book`, you just defined it for `Patron`.

Therefore you could call the read function on `Patron` like this

```
...  
catalog[k].checkIn();  
patrons[k].read(catalog[k]);  
...
```